# Make Image and text spin together

Tags: css

I want to rotate both image and text together. For example every 3 secs results will be like this

Use [Sheet Image] Google sheet and speed up your business

Use [Notes Image] Google Notes and speed up your business

Use [Docs Image] Google Docs and speed up your business

Use [Powerpoint Image] Google Powerpoints and speed up your business

Here [] will be replaced with

```
``<img src="../images/sheet.svg"></img>
```

and likewise for others

Without rotation the simple layout would look like this

```
  <h1>
              Say Use <span class="flex flexrow">
                <img src="./images/gsheet.svg"></img>
                <span>Google sheet</span>
              </span>   and speed up your business.
 </h1>
```

For just text, I was able to solve like this. But don't know how to add Image with it

```css
#rotate {

    height: 1.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #rotate:after {
    content: "";
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      content: "Google sheets";
    }
    25% {
      content: "Docs";
    }
  
    50% {
      content: "Powerpoint";
    }
    100% {
      content: "Notes";
    }
  }
```

```html
 <h1>
              Use <span class="flex flexrow">
                <span id="rotate"></span>
              </span>   and speed up your business.
 </h1>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as `</img>`. Remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do all this with css, then use [`content: url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content):

```css
h1 {
  /* optional */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 span:not(:last-child) {
  /* optional */
  margin-right: .3em;
}

#rotate:after {
  content: '';
  animation: rotate 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%, 100% {
    content: 'Google sheets';
  }
  25% {
    content: 'Docs';
  }
  50% {
    content: 'Powerpoint';
  }
  75% {
    content: 'Notes';
  }
}

#rotate-icon{
  /* optional */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  flex: none;
}

#rotate-icon:after {
  content: '';
  animation: rotate-icon 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-icon {
  0%, 100% {
    content: url('https://picsum.photos/36/36');
  }
  25% {
    content: url('https://picsum.photos/36/37');
  }
  50% {
    content: url('https://picsum.photos/36/35');
  }
  75% {
    content: url('https://picsum.photos/36/38');
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Use</span>
  <span id="rotate-icon"></span>
  <span id="rotate"></span>
  <span>and speed up your business.</span>
 </h1>
```

*P.S. Also I changed the keyframes of your animation because yours is incorrect.*